# Unable to dispay rows in proper order while reading csv file in PHP

Tags: php

I am unable to display row and Columns in proper order when opening in browser.
Expected output : hello,hello1,hello3,hello4,ff,hh,ii,jj
Actual output:hello,ff,hello1,hh,hello3,ii,hello4,jj

I need to iterate the Column1 and then column 2.Below is my CSV file and PHP code.

```
Name    position
hello   ff
hello1  hh
hello3  ii
hello4  jj

<?php
     $file = fopen('joinUs.csv', "r");
    while ($row = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ',')) {
        $colCount = count($row);

             for ($x=0; $x<$colCount; $x++) {
        echo "<ul>";
            echo "<li><a href='#".$row[$x]."'>$row[$x]|</a> </li>";
        echo "</ul>";
    }

    }

    fclose($file);



 ?>
```

Please let me know how i can iterate first column in PHP.I am new to PHP.

Comment: you need to move the `<ul>` and `</ul>` OUTSIDE of your for() loop, so they only get output ONCE for every csv row you read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to go through column 1 then column 2.  If we can assume you have a comma separated file then something like this should work:

```
<?php 
$file = fopen('joinUs.csv', "r");

# skip the first line with the titles.
fgets($file);

$first = array();
$second = array();

while ($row = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ','))
{
    # first column
    $first[] = trim($row[0]);

    # second column
    $second[] = trim($row[1]);
}

fclose($file);


echo "<ul>";
foreach( array_merge($first,$second) as $item )
{
    echo "<li><a href='#".$item."'>".$item."|</a> </li>";
}

echo "</ul>";

?>
```

The output is then:

```
<ul>
<li><a href='#hello'>hello|</a> </li>
<li><a href='#hello1'>hello1|</a> </li>
<li><a href='#hello3'>hello3|</a> </li>
<li><a href='#hello4'>hello4|</a> </li>
<li><a href='#position'>position|</a> </li>
<li><a href='#ff'>ff|</a> </li>
<li><a href='#hh'>hh|</a> </li>
<li><a href='#ii'>ii|</a> </li>
<li><a href='#jj'>jj|</a> </li>
</ul>
```

That is assuming you want to have the order as hello,hello1,hello3,hello4,ff,hh,ii,jj.

There might be a more efficient method but this should get you going.